# Centering stat_summary errorbars with position_dodge2

Tags: r, ggplot2, position

I can't seem to get these errorbars to center on the bars. I thought `position_dodge2(width=0.5)` would do the trick but changing the `width` argument doesn't seem to do anything?
Example:

```
    set.seed(1234)
    library(tidyverse)
    data.frame(rep=c(rep(1,15),rep(2,15)),
               num=rep(c(sample(c(1:15),15)),2),
               sex=rep(c(sample(c("m","f"),15,T))),
               conc=rep(c(rep("1:1000",5),rep("1:100",5),rep("1:10",5)),2),
               c1=c(sample(c(0:100),15,T),sample(c(0:100),15,T)),
               c2=c(sample(c(0:100),15,T),sample(c(0:100),15,T)),
               c3=c(sample(c(0:100),15,T),sample(c(0:100),15,T)),
               c4=c(sample(c(0:100),15,T),sample(c(0:100),15,T)))%>%
      pivot_longer(cols=c(c1,c2,c3,c4),
                   names_to="compound",
                   values_to="time")%>%
      ggplot(aes(x=compound,
                 y=time,
                 group=rep,
                 fill=as.factor(rep)))+
      stat_summary(fun="mean",geom="col",
                   position=position_dodge2(width=1))->p1
    p1+facet_grid(conc~.)
    p1+stat_summary(fun.data="mean_se",geom="errorbar",
                    width=0.5,
                    position=position_dodge2(width=0.5))+
      facet_grid(conc~.)
    p1+stat_summary(fun.data="mean_se",geom="errorbar",
                    width=0.5,
                    position=position_dodge2(width=1))+
      facet_grid(conc~.)
    p1+stat_summary(fun.data="mean_se",geom="errorbar",
                    width=0.5,
                    position=position_dodge2(width=0.1))+
      facet_grid(conc~.)
    p1+stat_summary(fun.data="mean_se",geom="errorbar",
                    width=0.5,
                    position=position_dodge(width=0.5))+
      facet_grid(conc~.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in `position_dodge2()` for dodging error bars, as I've encountered the same issue.  Dodging point geoms with `position_dodge2()` is similarly finnicky.

The fix would be to use `position_dodge()`, although you may have to play around a bit with the dodge with and the width of the geom itself to get things looking right:

```
p1 + stat_summary(fun.data="mean_se",geom="errorbar",
                width=0.5,
                position=position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
    facet_grid(conc~.)
```

[image]

Comment: Why set position_dodge(width=0.9) and not position_dodge(width=0.5) when width is 0.5?

Comment: It seems dodging is really strange when using error bars and doesn't really behave as you would expect.  In the case of `position_dodge2()`, it doesn't even work, and in the case of `position_dodge()`, you have to play around to get the dodge width correct (not working as intended).  I believe this is a bug.