# Centering Errorbars with position_dodge and position_dodge2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset comparing infections of two species of nematodes from two sources (lab reared and commercial). I want to make a barplot with errorbars comparing the four treatments to untreated controls but I can't seem to get the errorbars to behave the way I want them to.
Here is a working example:

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)

# create data
data.frame(source=c("Control",rep(c("Lab","Commercial"),2)),
           species=c("Control","A","A","B","B"),
           means=abs(rnorm(5,10,5)),
           ses=abs(rnorm(5,1,3)))%>%
  # plot the data
  ggplot(aes(x=species,
             y=means,
             ymin=means-ses,
             ymax=means+ses,
             fill=source))->p1
# option 1
p1+
  geom_col(position=position_dodge(preserve="single"))+
  geom_errorbar(width=0.4,
                position=position_dodge(width=0.9))
# option 2
p1+
  geom_col(position=position_dodge2(preserve="single"))+
  geom_errorbar(width=0.4,
                position=position_dodge2(width=0.9))
# option 3
p1+
  geom_col(position=position_dodge2(preserve="single"))+
  geom_errorbar(width=0.4,
                position=position_dodge(width=0.9))
# option 4
p1+
  geom_col(position=position_dodge(preserve="single"))+
  geom_errorbar(width=0.4,
                position=position_dodge2(width=0.9))
```

Which produce the following graphs:
[image: Option 1][image: Option 2][image: Option 3][image: Option 4]
Option 3 seems to get closest to what I am trying to do, but the errorbar width for control is too wide. I want all the bars to be the same width so I am using `preserve="single"`. I am using `position_dodge(width=0.9)` based off the answer I got to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835510/centering-stat-summary-errorbars-with-position-dodge2) about errorbars. It seems like no matter what I do the errorbar for control is ignoring the `width=0.4` argument. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need `preserve = 'single'` for your errorbar dodge too:

```r
p1 +
  geom_col(position  =position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.4,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.9, preserve = 'single'))
```

[image]

If you want the "control" column centralized, another approach might be to use "sneaky facets". Here's a full reprex:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)

data.frame(source = c("Control", rep(c("Lab", "Commercial"), 2)),
           species = c("Control", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
           means = abs(rnorm(5, 10, 5)),
           ses = abs(rnorm(5,1,3))) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = source,
             y = means,
             ymin = means - ses,
             ymax = means + ses,
             fill = source)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.4) +
  scale_x_discrete("Species", expand = c(0.1, 0.6)) +
  facet_grid(.~species, scales = 'free_x', space = 'free_x', switch = 'x') +
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, 'mm'),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>